# Remove fields(columns) in Django Models

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to remove some **fields(columns)** from the **Models.py** file. So, i make changes to the Models.py and `ran makemigrations`. It shows

> django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (removed field
>   names) specified for MODELNAME

I also tried running `python manage.py dbshell` and dropping the column from the table, made changes to remove the field from models.py and then running makemigrations. **It still shows the same error**. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You are probably using those removed fields in the admin.

Comment: Thank you, That was the issue!!

Answer (score -1):

If you've already removed the column from the database, then there probably isn't a lot of point anymore in making migrations. You should then just make sure that your `models.py` agrees with your database and you should be set.

I think initially there may have been some typo or other problem?

Comment: Yes, the formatting was not proper. I left it as you said without makemigrations(removed it from models.py too) and tried adding a dummy column into the model and did makemigrations, it shows the same error as i mentioned above although it is not present in models.py and the database. Thanks.